# Why does ImmutableSet allow duplicates, but ImmutableMap does not

Tags: java, duplicates, guava

I noticed (and appreciated!) that Guava's `ImmutableMap.Builder` fails to build if duplicate keys have been added to the builder.  Yet the same behavior (adding duplicate elements) succeeds with `ImmutableSet`.

Is there a reason for this difference, and any good way to construct an `ImmutableSet` with the same failure behavior?

Test case:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.*;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap;
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet;

public class ImmutableDuplicatesTest
{
    @Test(expectedExceptions=IllegalArgumentException.class) // Note failure
    public void mapDuplicates() {
        ImmutableMap.Builder<String, String> map = ImmutableMap.builder();
        map.put("a", "a");
        map.put("b", "b");
        map.put("a", "c");
        assertEquals(map.build().size(), 2);
    }

    @Test // Passes normally
    public void setDuplicates() {
        ImmutableSet.Builder<String> set = ImmutableSet.builder();
        set.add("a");
        set.add("b");
        set.add("a");
        assertEquals(set.build().size(), 2);
    }
}
```

Comment: My guess would be that, sets are designed that you can input the same thing twice and only have one copy of it. However with a map, if you map the same key to a new value, it overwrites the old one, and this may not be intended behaviour

Comment: However whether the value is the same or not has no bearing, it fails-fast on any duplicate key.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, this behavior is deliberate.  Here's one way of thinking about it: `Set`s are frequently created from other `Collection`s, especially `List`, which may have duplicates.  It'd be very awkward -- and inefficient -- to require users to write `ImmutableSet.copyOf(Sets.newHashSet(element))` if there might be duplicates.  On the other hand, `Map`s are typically built from other `Map`s, which can't have duplicate keys.

If you want to forbid duplicate elements, your best bet is something like

```
Set<E> set = new LinkedHashSet<E>();
for (E e : input) {
  if (!set.add(e)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
}
return ImmutableSet.copyOf(set);
```